# Replacing a string with a variable in a cURL command

Tags: linux, shell, curl, automation, groupme

I am trying to automate a GroupMe bot as simply as possible. An easy way to send a message from the command line is to use the following command:

```
curl -d '{"text" : "Your message here", "bot_id" : "this_is_a_secret_string"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post
```

In a Shell script, I would like to replace `"Your message here"` with `var`, in which `var` is being set to the output from a different command. Is this possible?

Things I have replaced "Your message here" with that did not work:

```
var
$var
(var)
$(var)
{var}
${var}
```

Anything put within double quotes ("") is treated as a String, so did not try much in those regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `var` will not be evaluated because it's w/in single quotes. One way around this is to just smash 3 strings together:

```
curl -d '{"text" : "'"$var"'Your message here", "bot_id" : "this_is_a_secret_string"}' https://api.groupme.com/v3/bots/post
```

- string 1: `'{"text" : "'`
- string 2: `"$var"`
- string 3: `'Your message here", "bot_id" : "this_is_a_secret_string"}'`

NOTE: this will only work if the contents of `var` are very simple. The expanded string must still be a valid JSON string.

Comment: worked flawlessly! didn't think of var needing double quotes, thanks a ton!